# Ember Integration Test for Closure Actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember-CLI 1.13.1, I have the following integration test in my component:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('category-tabs', 'Integration | Component | category tabs', {
  integration: true
});

test('tapping button fires an external action', function(assert) {
  this.on('onTabTouch', function(value) {
    assert.equal(value, 'Expense');
  });

  this.render(hbs`
    {{category-tabs onTabTouch=(action "onTabTouch")}}
  `);

  this.$('button:first').click();
});
```

Then in my component, I have this action:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    handleTabTouch(tab) {
      this.attrs.onTabTouch(tab);
    }
  }
});
```

My test keeps on saying this:

> An action named 'onTabTouch' was not found in [object Object].

How do I test a closure action? I also tried:

```
this.set('onTabTouch', function(value) {
  assert.equal(value, 'Expense');
});
```

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out.

Instead of writing:

```
this.on('onTabTouch', function(value) {
  assert.equal(value, 'Expense');
});
```

I wrote this:

```
this.set('actions', {
  onTabTouch(value) {
    assert.equal(value, 'Expense');
  }
});
```

EDIT:

A better way of doing it now is like this:

```
this.set('onTabTouch', () => assert.ok(true));

this.render(hbs`
  {{category-tabs onTabTouch=(action onTabTouch)}}
`);
```

Notice that `(action onTabTouch)` doesn't have any double quotes.

Comment: thank you - curious about how to patch this in today :)

Comment: The latter should work. I've been using that until now. Is it not for you?

Comment: first up I had a string based action (didn't work with closure actions) -using your example got me a working test :)